# I am getting an error when attempting to use sendgrid to send email

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am receiving an error, which I believe is coming back from sendgrid. However, I cannot find this error in Twilio/Sendgrid troubleshooting documentation. I've seen some references to it that indicate that this an issue with a version mismatch. Here's the thing, I know very little about this project. The dev left a while back. I've been trying to help, and fairly successful. However, this one has me stumped. The error doesn't refer to any line number, or module (that I can tell)

this is from the Firebase console log for the cloud function that is attempted to send this email:

```
{ 
 insertId: "000000-55176214-acd2-453d-8258-048000f1e9e3"   
   labels: {…}   
 logName: "projects/wsos-base/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"   
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-06-21T16:40:19.541487656Z"   
   resource: {…}   
 severity: "ERROR"   
 textPayload: "TypeError: Object.values is not a function"   
 timestamp: "2019-06-21T16:40:13.253Z"   
 trace: "projects/wsos-base/traces/bdb710bad4f92297c239de4409de2323"   
}
```

The console log messages BEFORE the sendgrid.send call are showing in the log. None of the log messages AFTER this call are showing. I've commented out the entire call, and no error shows in the log file. I'm almost 100% certain this is occurring in the call. BUT, from looking up sendgrid stuff, I should be expecting at least an error number in response.I confirmed that the 'catch' is working, by substituting a string error message. I do see that error message in the log. When I put it back to original catch, I get the reported "TypeError...Object.values…" message. No error message. No line number. No module.

```
return admin.auth().getUser(user)
                      .then(mentorObj => {
                        var mentorEmail = mentorObj.email;
                        var menteeObj = doc2.data();
                        console.log("Sending to Mentor: ", mentorEmail);
                        const confirmationMentor = {
                              to: mentorEmail,
                              from: *******,
                              template_id: ********,    
                              dynamicTemplateData: {
                                name: mentor.firstName,
                             menteeName: "MenteeNameHere"
                          },
                        };
                        console.log("Sent to Mentor: ", confirmationMentor);

                        return sendgrid.send(confirmationMentor)
                          .then(() => {
                            // console.log('Confirmation successfully sent to ' + mentorEmail);
                            console.log("sending to mentee");
...
})
                         .catch(error => console.error(error.toString()));
```

Simply replacing the above "error.toString()" with "SomeText" replaces the TypeError message in the console with "SomeText". Also, "sending to mentee" is NOT in the console logs. Additionally ".values" is NOT referenced anywhere in all of the source code.

In the console logs, I see the JSON being passed:

```
{ to: '*****',
  from: '*****',
  template_id: '******',
  dynamicTemplateData: { name: 'Rocky McChocolate', menteeName: 'MenteeNameHere' } }
```

I put this in an online JSON validator, and it is invalid. However, I believe that is because of how it is displayed in the log, and not how the JSON actually looks. Since this was working, and all I changed was the template id.
well, I think I've described this above (perhaps in the wrong place).
Client has a firebase app, and it sends out emails. They wanted a different email. So, I created the email (in Twilio/Sendgrid), and changed the template_id value and expected new email to be sent. Instead I get this error message. I've confirmed with the client that the emails were being sent prior to me working on it.

Answer (score 0):

That error, `"TypeError: Object.values is not a function"` is coming from your code, not from SendGrid. Somewhere, something is calling `.values` in an invalid way, but it's not in the code that you've shown here.

You're right that that is not valid JSON. Do you need to be calling a `toJSON` or similar on the values, to convert it to a JSON String?

Comment: No, this is NOT coming from the code. ".values" is NOT being called in the code. This error is being caught as follows:    .catch(error => console.error(error.toString()));  Not sure why, but I cannot add cr/lf (press Enter) or each time I do it saves the changes. The SendGrid endpoint requires JSON. I believe the reason the JSON is invalid is due to the formatting that console.log performs to write out the JSON. The lines that create the JSON are valid

Comment: To further describe this. I have added console.log messages before and after the "return sendgrid.send(confirmationMentor).then(…).catch(error => console.error(error.toString())). I only see the log messages that occur BEFORE the sendgrid call. When I simply replace "error.toString()" with "This is where the error is caught", I get that text INSTEAD of the TypeError… message. Also, in the .then() block, the first thing I do is place a console.log message, which NEVER appears. Just in case something in the .then block was causing the error. It is NOT.